# AX 2012 R2 CU7: AIF server setup

Tags: configuration, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, server, aif

Previously, we had AIF services installed on the same box as the AOS. Something happened with the AIF services and they stopped working using HTTP inbound ports. So, We installed AIF on a new server. What should we do to point to the new AIF server?

Verifying servers:

1. When I look at the ax32serv.exe.config file, all the endpoint references still point to the **old server**.
2. When I refresh from the client configuration utility, I get the error: An error occurred while regenerating WCF configuration: Unable to connect to a Microsoft Dynamics AX WCF service......Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: http://**old-server**:8101/DynamicsAX/services/RfsCqrsServices

Both ways show that we are still pointing to the old server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried the following:

1. Stop the AOS
2. Edit ax32serv.exe.config, specify the new server details where required
3. Start the AOS
4. Generate full CIL

Comment: Hmmm...I guess that is an option. AX allows you to have multiple AIF servers simultaneously. Is there a way to specify the new server while maintaining the old, though broken?

Comment: If you can find another solution it'll be interesting to learn it.